# Extract variables from querystring

Tags: c#, regex, text-parsing

I need to parse the following string

```
/MyData.csv(MemberCount.sum,Production.sum[Salesperson="James Almond","Area="Europe "Area 1" (Germany)",Area="North America",Area="North America [Level A]"])
```

The first part is easy, however the clause within the brackets ([]) is giving me a bit of headache since it can contain double quotes as the example shows. (note the content within the brackets can change dynamically)

I expect the following output when parsing the last part of the string :

Salesperson
    James Almond
    Area
    Europe "Area 1" (Germany)
    Area
    North America
    Area
    North America [Level A]

I've been working with regex but can't seem to get it right. Hoping someone have the magic!

Comment: what if you simply did String.Split() on "Area=" and did a little post manipulation?

Comment: I realize that my example should have had another example, Area could be substituted with another label as well like "CountryName" (it depends on the columns being queried)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may give a try to the [Balancing Group Definitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#balancing_group_definition):

```
string pattern = @"^[^\[\]]*" +
                @"(" +
                @"((?'Open'\[)[^\[\]]*)+" +
                @"((?'Close-Open'\])[^\[\]]*)+" +
                @")*" +
                @"(?(Open)(?!))$";

var results =
    Regex.Match(input, pattern)
    .Groups["Close"].Value
    .Split(new char[] { '=', ',' });
```

This outputs:

```
Salesperson
"James Almond"
Area
"Europe "Area 1" (Germany)"
Area
"North America"
Area
"North America [Level A]"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that the 'true' closing double quotes are either followed by a comma or the closing square bracket:

```
Area="(?<Area>.*?)"(?=\]|,)
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/pI0bT1).

Comment: Thanks Jerry. regex101 demo is very useful. I edited the question a bit as I didn't realize I made the data a bit too uniform.

Comment: @ptrdk You're welcome! Also, is the part within the square brackets you need the only part with the format `word = "word"`? If so, you can use this: `(\w+)="(.*?)"(?=\]|,)` ([updated regex101](http://regex101.com/r/iU2zM6)). If that's that, I'll update my answer with it.